# PSU requiring often cable change

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, power-management, cable

I seem to be having a strange issue with my PSU that I use for my computer.
Long story short, I built my own computer about 1-2 months ago, and was having no trouble with it for about the first month.
About that point in time, my computer suddenly just stopped turning on. I tried a different PSU cable and suprisingly it worked for about another fortnight, where it happened again. Swap it out, works fine.

My PSU is a Thermaltake 500W W0410 and I bought all of my parts brand new. I tried connecting my "faulty"  cable straight into the powerpoint/wall socket instead of a powerboard, but the same issue persists. Could this possibly be a computer issue? PSU issue? If more specs are required, I'm happy to provide them.

What could possibly be causing this "faultiness" in the cables? I'm swapping the new ones out for the old ones that were previously "broken" yet they work fine.

Comment: I have no idea what a powerpoint is

Comment: @Ramhound :O Well then, I guess for my whole life I've been using Australian slang. What I mean is, a "wall socket".

Comment: What is the powerboard?

Comment: @Ramhound Oh my god, I did it again. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_strip

Comment: I suppose what could be going on is a fuse is being triggered, by unplugging the PSU, your resetting it in some way. This indicates the PSU should be replaced

Comment: @Ramhound *sigh* I just bought the damn thing... Suppose that is true though, when I unplug it and put the same cord in, it won't work? I have to swap them around each time.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Could be that you're blowing fuses. Could you try replacing a fuse on a 'dead' cable and see if it works?

Comment: @frayment Why the accusation?

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, I'm not in any way saying it to you, just a comment for whoever it is if they read it. I tend to use it alot.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I wouldn't have a clue how. It couldn't possibly be a blown fuse, the old cables, I literally just stick in a cupboard and leave them until I need to "swap them out" again.

Comment: wait, so a *swapped* cable that didn't work before work? Ok, that's just strange

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I know right. It happened this morning and I tried the old one which previously didn't work and it worked. That prompted me to ask this question because what on earth is going on.

Comment: +1 for using perfectly understandable language (at least to a pom) :)

Comment: @ChrisA All hail British English, superior to all other dialects. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after all this time, it turns out I solved the issue.
Whatever the issue was, the PSU was not the fault.

To begin, the cable changes were strange, and my PSU almost had some sort of ghostly "memory", where it wouldn't let the computer turn on if I swapped between two cords. I had to use three or more, in a set order. If I went back and forth in the ordering of my cable swaps, it wouldn't work.

Then it stopped working completely, so I opened it up and looked online.
Turns out the only issue was that **I had to replace the tiny button battery in the motherboard**, as the shop I bought it off obviously had it sitting there long enough to kill the thing.

The power cable issues must have just been zapping the battery giving it a tiny bit of life. As to why I needed specific ordering, maybe the house is haunted. :/

Problem solved.

Comment: cmos battery deaths do the darnedest things